# Google Maps API v2 Android...blank screen & no pin

Tags: android, api, google-maps

I have a signed Android APK which runs perfectly on Android 4.0.4, but will not display the maps on Android 4.2.2.

According to many websites, usually blank maps is caused by key authentication issues with the Google API, however I reckon I can rule that out because it works fine on 4.0.4.

Can anyone suggest anything else that I could investigate?

Thanks

Update - I can run the app from Eclipse onto a device running Android 4.0.4 and the maps work correctly. When I run the same app in the same Eclipse environment onto a device running Android 4.4 the maps will not display and I get the following messages in the logcat...

```
============== Start of Logcat ===========================

12-23 23:17:20.744: D/dalvikvm(15675): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 627K, 10% free 9473K/10516K, paused 40ms, total 42ms

12-23 23:17:20.904: D/dalvikvm(15675): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 469K, 11% free 9462K/10516K, paused 85ms, total 85ms

12-23 23:17:21.034: D/dalvikvm(15675): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 480K, 10% free 9479K/10516K, paused 65ms, total 65ms

**12-23 23:17:47.484: I/HostnameVerifier- checkServerTrusted(15675): CertificateException - clients4.google.com - java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.**

12-23 23:18:17.654: D/dalvikvm(15675): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 599K, 10% free 9496K/10516K, paused 22ms, total 22ms

12-23 23:18:17.664: I/HostnameVerifier- checkServerTrusted(15675): CertificateException - clients4.google.com - java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

12-23 23:18:47.774: I/HostnameVerifier- checkServerTrusted(15675): CertificateException - clients4.google.com - java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

============== End of Logcat ===========================
```

Update -
Permissions from the manifest file...

```
<permission android:name="uk.co.bluefinsoftware.fusionmobile.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
                android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="uk.co.bluefinsoftware.fusionmobile.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
```

Comment: Remember that you have to put a different key if it's a signed Android APK, and not the debbug one. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of the 2 different keys. But surely if I was using the debug key, it would not work in either Android version?

Comment: Maybe there is some Permissions not setted.

Comment: Hi Tsunaze, I've added the permissions to the original post.

Comment: When you reinstall your app with a new key, delete your app completely  or erase the data app, because it can retain the previous Google key, it happens sometime.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago was not, but now

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

is a compulsory field in your `AndroidManifest.xml` under the `<application>` tag.

And of course, double check every step (I suppose you already have done it once at least) because from time to time, this minor changes can be the key.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have this in my AndroidManifest.xml file. Again, if this was missing, surely it would not work on both Android devices.

Answer (score 0):

What is your problem i do not know but i think you will follow below link again step by step then may be u will sure success.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Comment: My Maps display correctly on devices running Android 4.0.4 but do not display on devices running Android 4.2.2 and above (all I get is a blank screen where the map & pin should be).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this might not be a problem with your map setup, but with your device configuration.  According to my research, this CertException seems to be caused mostly by trying to use https, are you trying to make a connection somewhere that's getting rejected?  Also, what is clients4.google.com?

I would try verifying that your app doesn't work on another 4.4 device, if you have one available, and also check the settings for the device, such as Security->Trusted Credentials.  I might also try resetting the device if that's an option.

Comment: Hi GLee, thanks for the reply. I've tried it on 6 devices as follows;

Comment: Sorry Glee...didn't get to finish editing the above comment......Hi GLee, thanks for the reply. I've tried it on 6 devices as follows; 1xAndroid 4.0.3  1xAndroid 4.0.4  2xAndroid 4.2.2  2xAndroid 4.4   and the only ones it works on are 4.0.3 & 4.0.4.